# Collision detection stop movement

Tags: opengl, c++, 3d

I am making a simple first person 3D game in OpenGL with C++. I am just wondering on how you make an object stop moving when it collides with another object. This is what I am using for detecting collisions:

```
a = object1
b = object2
w = width
object1 is moving on X,Y,and Z axes from user input

if( a.x + a.w > b.x && a.x < b.x + b.w )
(and the same thing for X, Y, and Z axis)
```

After detecting this collision how would I make "object1" stop moving?

Comment: We have lots of past Q&A about [tag:collision-resolution] — what have you tried based on your research thus far?

Comment: You use a c++ physics engine?

Comment: It would help if you provided some info about how movement is being applied to `object1`.